# Software & Updates: when there are security updates. Empty list, no item can be selected

Tags: 22.04

How to return normal "when there are security updates" list in Software & Updates application? Now there is empty string. Ubuntu 22.04.2 Jammy Jellyfish.

[image]

grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

```
grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
/etc/apt/sources.list:#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20230223)]/ jammy main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-apps.list:deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-apps.list:# deb-src https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-apps.list:deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-updates main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-apps.list:# deb-src https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-updates main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.list:deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-security main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.list:# deb-src https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-security main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.list:deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-updates main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.list:# deb-src https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-updates main
```

tail /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log

```
tail /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log
2023-04-23 08:59:36,050 INFO Запускаются сценарии необслуживаемой установки
2023-04-23 08:59:36,050 INFO Разрешённые источники: o=Ubuntu,a=jammy, o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=jammy-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=jammy-infra-security
2023-04-23 08:59:36,050 INFO Initial blacklist: 
2023-04-23 08:59:36,050 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict): 
2023-04-23 08:59:37,136 WARNING Could not figure out development release: Distribution data outdated. Please check for an update for distro-info-data. See /usr/share/doc/distro-info-data/README.Debian for details.
2023-04-23 08:59:37,136 INFO Запускаются сценарии необслуживаемой установки
2023-04-23 08:59:37,137 INFO Разрешённые источники: o=Ubuntu,a=jammy, o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=jammy-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=jammy-infra-security
2023-04-23 08:59:37,137 INFO Initial blacklist: 
2023-04-23 08:59:37,137 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict): 
2023-04-23 08:59:38,674 INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

Comment: Does `apt list --upgradable` show anything?.

Comment: No, apt shows empty list as well.

Comment: I guess you could try reinstalling the software properties common and GTK.  `sudo apt install --reinstall software-properties-common software-properties-gtk`  If not, you might be experiencing a bug with the software-properties-gtk app.

Comment: @Terrance, I tried reinstall it. The issue is not solved.

Comment: I will watch what happens with the security updates.

Comment: @user535733 The listbox control "when there are security updates" is disabled.

Comment: I have added the picture. I don't want to reinstall the whole OS because of this bug.

Comment: You've set `Automtically check for updates` to `never`, that's the reason why `When there are security updates` is inactive.

Comment: @mook765 When I set "Automtically check for updates" to daily, "When there are security updates" is still inactive.

Comment: `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` please.

Comment: Also please show us `tail /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log`. Check the timestamps. We want to see if unattended upgrades is running daily despite the missing setting.

Comment: @nobody I have added output to the question

Comment: @user535733 I have added output to the question

Comment: The log output looks like Unattended Upgrades (security updates) is running normally despite the setting. That suggests perhaps a mere papercut bug in one of the `software-properties-*` packages instead of a high-priority failure of apt. You are still getting security patches.

Comment: Thanks, I will ignore it.

Comment: I just tested it, if you set the "Automatically check" to `Never` then close out of the app, when going back in the "When there are Security Updates..." is not selectable.  You have to exit the app after each change you make then relaunch it for the settings to take effect.

Comment: @Terrance Yes, you are right. I fixed it exiting application after each change. Thanks. You can write it as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make any changes to the Software & Updates you will need to exit and restart it for the changes to take effect.

*Setting the "Automatic check" to Never still shows "When there are security updates available" as selectable:*

[image]

*Restarting the app now "When there are security updates available" is not selectable:*

[image]

*Setting the "Automatic check" to Daily still shows "When there are security updates available" as not selectable:*

[image]

*Restarting the app now "When there are security updates available" is  selectable:*

[image]

Comment: +1 Excellent troubleshooting!